# how to create a table view with multiple columns

Tags: ios, mysql, uitableview, xcode6

I want to fill a table view with various data in the column as shown in the picture but not if you can do or how to do it:

[image]

also should be possible to select each row to open a new ViewController com more information from the contents of the row, I appreciate your help on how to enable this table or can be made with another object.

Comment: use UICollectionView instead of UITableView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create custom Header View to show table header and Design custom `UITableViewCell` containing 4 `UILabel`s  at required positions to show as columns.